# using Find -exec to rename a file with the grepped contents of the file

Tags: find, rename, pdf, mv

I'm attempting to get a list of files with find and then use pdfgrep to get a string from the file, then rename the file with that string.

The commands broken down are:

```
find . -name "*PayrollSelfBill_42652301*" -exec pdfgrep {}  -o -e "42652301-.{10}"
```

the find gets the files i'm interested in, the pdfgrep in the -exec portion pulls out the right string.

I want to mv the file held in {} to the output from pdfgrep.

I've tried creating variables (with $()/ backticks) and multiple -execs but can't seem to get anything to work.

Does anyone have and elegant solution?

Comment: Start with this Q&A - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find/389706#389706.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file, `$filename`, you would, if I understand you correctly, want to do something like

```
mv -i "$filename" "$( pdfgrep "$filename" -o -e "42652301-.{10}" )"
```

... assuming `$filename` was a name of a file in the current directory. Right?  If not, the code below would not be correct either...

Ok, let's plug that into `find` with an `-execdir`:

```
find . -type f -name "*PayrollSelfBill_42652301*" -execdir sh -c '
    filename=$1
    mv -i "$filename" "$( pdfgrep "$filename" -o -e "42652301-.{10}" )"' sh {} ';'
```

This would find the files that you are interested in and run the script fragment *in the same directory as where the file was found* (this is how `-execdir` differs from `-exec`).

It's possible that

```
find . -type f -name "*PayrollSelfBill_42652301*" \
    -execdir mv -i {} "$( pdfgrep {} -o -e "42652301-.{10}" )" ';'
```

would work too, actually, without the added child shell... now that I think about it.  But I would feel safer calling a child shell since `-execdir` is a nonstandard option in `find`.

---

Assuming `$pathname` is one of the found files, but it's *not* in the current directory, then the following would do the same for that file:

```
mv -i "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/$( pdfgrep "$pathname" -o -e "42652301-.{10}" )"
```

Here, `${pathname%/*}` would expand to the directory of the found file (it's the same as `$( dirname "$pathname" )`).

This might work

```
find . -type f -name "*PayrollSelfBill_42652301*" \
    -exec  mv -i {} "$( dirname {} )/$( pdfgrep {} -o -e "42652301-.{10}" )" ';'
```

But we can be a bit more efficient and use `-exec ... {} +` to process a bunch of files in batch:

```
find . -type f -name "*PayrollSelfBill_42652301*" -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv -i "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/$( pdfgrep "$pathname" -o -e "42652301-.{10}" )"
    done' sh {} +
```

The difference from the `-execdir` solution above is that only one (or very few) `sh -c` scripts would be started, and `dirname` is replaced by a quicker substitution, making it potentially quicker than the variation just previous to it.

Relate to both variations in this answer:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)